# Автоматизирование GUI windows

Tags: python, windows

Нужна программа которая бы открывала приложение windows, получала доступ к его GUI и вводила нужные данные, без захвата мыши и клавиатуры.

Возможно ли такое реализовать?
Если да, то через какие библиотеки?
Возможно кто-то покажет подобный код на примере.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Может pywinauto подойдет. https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @СергейКох Спасибо это библиотека отлично подходит для автоматизации GUI. Вот только как оказалось мне нужна другая т.к. моя программа это не GUI, а консольное приложение. Буду пробовать через subprocess.